# How can I use controller return bean <list> to Ajax, and show them on a table?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm using SpringMVC,and I have a problem.

I want to do a searching method. The button can push the data to the controller by Ajax, and actually it work! but I don't know how to display the bean list on the view table.

**JSP**

```
<body>
<script>
function queryForm() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',   
            url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Student/searchStudent',
            data:{stuNo: $('#stuNoSingle').val()},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("data");  
            },  
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
                }
        });

}
</script>

<br> <br> 單一條件：學號查詢：
        <table width="100%" border=1>
            <tr>
                <td>學號： <input type="text" id="stuNoSingle">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onclick="queryForm();">查詢</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <br>
    <br>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

@RequestMapping("/searchStudent")
    public @ResponseBody List<StudentBean> searchStudent(StudentBean StudentBean) throws Exception {
        List<StudentBean> sbList = studentService.search(StudentBean);
        System.out.println("controller List="+sbList);
        return sbList;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `alert("data");` give you ?

Comment: Whats the value you are getting in response?

Comment: just object Object

Comment: and this is my web console:  [{…}]
0
:
address
:
"台北"
class_
:
"資管1甲"
gender
:
"男"
name
:
"王遠"
password
:
"Jarvan1110"
phone
:
"0968620374"
status
:
"100"
stuNo
:
"10646029"
teacher
:
"rc"
type
:
"四技"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: you need to iterate  response array

Comment: Add console.log(data); and press f12 to check the web logs what you are getting in object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jqGrid...sample code below for user list

```js
var options=null;
var counter=0;
var URL = $('#contextpath').val() + '/page/User';
var selectedUser=null;
var enable = null;

(function($) {
 options = $("#usergrid").jqGrid({
      url:URL,
      editUrl:URL,
      datatype: 'json',
   mtype: 'GET',
      colNames:['Id', 'User ID', 'Name', 'Email'],
      colModel:[
       {name:'id',index:'id', editable:false, editoptions:{readonly:true, size:5}, hidden:true},
       {name:'userid',index:'userid', width:90, editable:false},
       {name:'name',index:'name', width:90, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
       {name:'email',index:'email', width:100, sortable:false, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10},formatter:returnEmailUserLink},
      ],
      postData: {},
   rowNum:10,
      rowList:[10,20,40,60],
      height: 'auto',
      autowidth: true,
      pager: '#userpager',
      sortname: 'userid',
      viewrecords: true,
      sortorder: "asc",
      emptyrecords: "Empty records",
      multiselect: false,
      loadonce: false,
      //altRows: true,
      loadComplete: function() {
       $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#f0f9ff");
          $("tr.jqgrow:even").css("background", "#fff");
       counter=0;
       count = $('#usergrid').getGridParam("records");
       
       if(count==0) { 
         $("#userrec").show();   
       }else{
        $("#userrec").hide();  
       }
     },
      jsonReader : {
          root: "rows",
          page: "page",
          total: "total",
          records: "max",
          repeatitems: false,
          cell: "cell",
          id: "id"
      }
  });

  $("#usergrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#userpager',
    {edit:false, add:false, del:false, search:false},
    {}, {}, {}       
  );
  
  
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to iterate your response as

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    //now you can access properties using dot notation
    // item.address, item.gender & so on ...
});
```

Or using simple for loop

```
for( var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i ) {
    //now you can access properties from array
    // data[i].address, data[i].gender & so on ...
}
```

In for loop append data to your table using [jQuery.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method Or any form of append method.

**Don't expose your password in JSON array In your bean try `@JsonIgnore` annotation**

Comment: can I display the data with <c:forEach items="">?

Comment: yes, but not with ajax call, `<c:forEach items="">` used at server side